# EF6-Lambda Expressions deep big-tree query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I am looking to improve the following query.

We are using EF6 (CodeFirst) and C# Lambda Expressions, and Repository/Unit of Work patterns. Also, we needed to restrict the query in a way that we could inner-query the entities so that the query will only retrieve a subset of the joined data, and found this [DynamicSelectExtensions](https://github.com/thiscode/DynamicSelectExtensions) library that extends `IQueryable` and gives us a `SelectIncluding` statement so that we could do this.

**Query:**

```
namespace Repositorios
{
    public class CanalDeComunicacionRepositorio: EFRepositorioDesactivable<CanalDeComunicacion>, ICanalDeComunicacionRepositorio
    {
        public CanalDeComunicacionRepositorio(DbContext context) : base(context) { }

        public IQueryable<CanalDeComunicacion> ConsultaParaLibreria()
        {
            return
                dbSet.Where(canalComunicacion=> canalComunicacion.FechaDesactivacion==null)
                .SelectIncluding(new List<Expression<Func<CanalDeComunicacion, object>>>()
                {
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Where(controlador=>controlador.FechaDesactivacion==null),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaPuertas.Where(puerta=>puerta.FechaDesactivacion==null)),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaPuertas.Select( puerta=>puerta.ListaLectoras.Where(lectora=>lectora.FechaDesactivacion==null))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Where(lectora=>lectora.FechaDesactivacion==null)),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaEventosExcluidos.Where(eventos=> eventos.FechaDesactivacion==null)),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Where(grupoLectora=>grupoLectora.FechaDesactivacion==null && grupoLectora.GrupoAcceso.FechaDesactivacion==null))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGpoPadre.Where(gpoPadre => gpoPadre.FechaDesactivacion==null)))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGpoPadre.Select(gpoPadre => gpoPadre.GpoPadre)))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGpoPadre.Select(gpoPadre => gpoPadre.GpoPadre.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Where(listEmp => listEmp.FechaDesactivacion==null))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGpoPadre.Select(gpoPadre => gpoPadre.GpoPadre.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Select(listEmp => listEmp.Persona))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGpoPadre.Select(gpoPadre => gpoPadre.GpoPadre.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Select(listEmp => listEmp.Persona.ListaTarjetaPersona.Where(tarPer=>tarPer.FechaDesactivacion==null)))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGpoPadre.Select(gpoPadre => gpoPadre.GpoPadre.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Select(listEmp => listEmp.Persona.ListaTarjetaPersona.Select(tarPer=>tarPer.Tarjeta)))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGpoPadre.Select(gpoPadre => gpoPadre.GpoPadre.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Select(listEmp => listEmp.Persona.ListaTarjetaPersona.Select(tarPer=>tarPer.Tarjeta.ListaTiposTarjeta.Where(ltipo=>ltipo.FechaDesactivacion==null))))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeFeriados.Where(liferiado=> liferiado.FechaDesactivacion==null)))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Where(lisEmpleado=> lisEmpleado.FechaDesactivacion==null)))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeFeriados.Select(liferiado=> liferiado.Feriado)))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeHistorialTurnosRecurrencia.Where(turno=>turno.FechaDesactivacion==null)))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeHistorialTurnosRecurrencia.Select(turno=>turno.Turno).Select(turno=>turno)))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeHistorialTurnosRecurrencia.Select(turno=>turno.Turno).Select(turno=>turno.ListaDiasHora.Where(lista=>lista.FechaDesactivacion==null))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeHistorialTurnosRecurrencia.Select(turno=>turno.Turno).Select(turno=>turno.ListaDiasHora.Select(lista=>lista.Dia))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Select(lisEmpleado=> lisEmpleado.Persona)))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Select(grupoEmpleado=>grupoEmpleado.ListaDeHistorialTurnosRecurrenciaEspecial.Where(listaTurnoRecurrencia=> listaTurnoRecurrencia.FechaDesactivacion==null))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Select(grupoEmpleado=>grupoEmpleado.ListaDeHistorialTurnosRecurrenciaEspecial.Select(turno=>turno.Turno))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Select(grupoEmpleado=>grupoEmpleado.ListaDeHistorialTurnosRecurrenciaEspecial.Select(turno=>turno.Turno.ListaDiasHora.Where(lista=>lista.FechaDesactivacion==null)))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Select(grupoEmpleado=>grupoEmpleado.ListaDeHistorialTurnosRecurrenciaEspecial.Select(turno=>turno.Turno.ListaDiasHora.Select(lista=>lista.Dia)))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Select(lisEmpleado=> lisEmpleado.Persona.ListaTarjetaPersona.Where(lisTarjeta=>lisTarjeta.FechaDesactivacion==null))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Select(lisEmpleado=> lisEmpleado.Persona.ListaTarjetaPersona.Select(lisTarjeta=>lisTarjeta.Tarjeta))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora.Select(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGrupoAccesoEmpleados.Select(lisEmpleado=> lisEmpleado.Persona.ListaTarjetaPersona.Select(lisTarjeta=>lisTarjeta.Tarjeta.ListaTiposTarjeta.Where(list=>list.FechaDesactivacion==null)))))),
                    canalComunicacion => canalComunicacion.ListaControladores2.Select(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras.Select(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaTiposTarjeta.Where(list=>list.FechaDesactivacion==null)))
                }).AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}
```

The query just works as of right now, but it is a very slow query, and also the code is pretty ugly and long and nested.

**Model:**

This is the data model for the entities involved in the query. As you can see, we need to join a lot of tables and traverse the tree to get all the data we need.

[image: Data Model]

EDIT:

About the patterns we are using, they al are proposed by Julie Lerman and her recommendations for Entity Framework use in the enterprise.
The solution layout includes these projects:

- DomainClasses: all classes that are used in the data model.
- DataLayer: DbContext is defined here, along with migrations, tables, special model configurations and seed data.
- Repositorio and IRepositorio (Repositories): Here is all the logic that handles EF, in addition to UOW.

This structure helps us to have a single point of entry to the data, easing development and maintenance of our application.

Inside the Repositorio project, we have a generic repository (EFRepositorio) from which all of the specific repository implementations inherit:

```
namespace Repositorios
{
    public class EFRepositorio<T> : IRepositorio<T> where T : class
    {
        protected DbContext dbContext { get; set; }
        protected DbSet<T> dbSet { set; get; }

        public EFRepositorio(DbContext dbcontext)
        {
            if (dbcontext == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("dbContext es Nulo");
            dbContext = dbcontext;
            dbSet = dbContext.Set<T>();

        }

        public virtual IQueryable<T> DameTodos()
        {
            return dbSet;

        }

        public virtual T DamePorId(int id)
        {
            return dbSet.Find(id);
        }


        public virtual void Agregar(T entity)
        {
            DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = dbContext.Entry(entity);

            if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Detached)
            {
                dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Added;
            }
            else
            {
                dbSet.Add(entity);
            }
        }

        public virtual void AgregarActualizarGrafo(T entity)
        {
            dbSet.Add(entity);
            dbContext.ApplyStateChanges();
        }

        public virtual void Actualizar(T entity)
        {
            AgregarActualizarGrafo(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Borrar(T entity)
        {
            DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = dbContext.Entry(entity);
            if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Deleted)
            {
                dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
            }
            else
            {
                dbSet.Attach(entity);
                dbSet.Remove(entity);
            }
        }

        public virtual void Borrar(int id)
        {
            var entity = DamePorId(id);

            if (entity == null) return;
            Borrar(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You *do* realize that Entity Framework's `DbContext` *is* a unit-of-work, right? `DbSet<T>` *is* a repository, too... why make an abstraction of an abstraction?

Comment: Where is `dbSet` coming from? You might get a more thorough review if you also include the code for the base class you're deriving from.

Comment: Please check my edit!! I've included the requested information. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the sql table create script, or explain what you are trying to query, or the sql query that the above code is resulting in? I don't understand the language it's in so it's hard for me to understand what you are trying to accomplish with the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should replace some of your `Selects` for `SelectMany`. Normally IEnumerable extensions can be coded without nesting them, in your case if you replace your "grupoAcesso" selction by chaining `SelectManys` you could write this:

```
private IEnumerable<?> GetGrupoAcessoFromCanal(CanalDeComunicacion canal){
    return canal.ListaControladores2
        .SelectMany(controlador=>controlador.ListaLectoras)
        .SelectMany(lectoras=>lectoras.ListaDeGruposAccesoLectora)
        .SelectMany(grupoAcceso=>grupoAcceso.GrupoAcceso);
}
```

This is also a query that is repeated way too much and that's why I placed it in a method, now let just use it:

```
dbSet.Where(canalComunicacion=> canalComunicacion.FechaDesactivacion==null)
     .SelectIncluding(new List<Expression<Func<CanalDeComunicacion, object>>>()
     {
        //all queries that don't need our method.
        canalComunication => GetGrupoAcessoFromCanal(canalComunication),
        canalComunication => GetGrupoAcessoFromCanal(canalComunication).Select(grupo=>grupo.ListaDeGpoPadre.Where(gpoPadre => gpoPadre.FechaDesactivacion==null)),
        //so on so forth...
     }
```

You should also apply this concept for all other nested queries that you have. Having your queries written in this way makes your code way more readable and natural.